# Writing a makefile for a kernel module

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel

I want to write a Kernel Module and now I have written some files: a.c, b.c, b.h and d.h.

a.c includes b.h and d.h and b.h includes d.h too.

I wrote a Makefile like this:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
mymodule-objs :=a.c b.c
obj-m += a.o b.o
else
PWD := $(shell pwd)
KVER := $(shell uname -r)
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(KVER)/build
all:
    rm -rf *.o *.mod.c *.symvers *order *.markers *.cmd *-
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD)
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.mod.c *.symvers *order *.markers *.cmd *-
endif
```

But it doesn't work, how should I write a correct Makefile? I want to get a file name x.ko in end and.

After I use the 'make' command, and I use 'insmod' is give me a message:

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module a.ko: Unknown symbol in module

By the way I use Ubuntu 14.10. The kernel is 3.16.0-37-generic

Comment: Can you elaborate on `But it doesn't work`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh After I use the 'make' command,and I use 'insmod' is give me a message:

**insmod: ERROR: could not insert module a.ko: Unknown symbol in module**

Comment: So that maybe a problem with your code also....

Comment: Is the .ko file generated? Is .ko file in a "visible" path?

Comment: @LPs In the end I got 2 .ko file, they are a.ko and b.ko

Comment: As @SouravGhosh wrote: this is a problem in your source code.

Comment: why use a makefile when the first thing you do is a complete rm-clean?

Comment: @PeterMiehle I just want to get a new file every time a use make

Comment: The intention to use a makefile is, to keep the "result" up to date according to changes made to any of the files. So when you change a.c, only a.o is to be rebuild (and everything that depends on a.o) but not b.o

Answer (score 1):

```
obj-m += a.o b.o
```

will create two modules, a.ko and b.ko
if you want to create a single module out of both (which I suppose you do because of the line with `mymodule-objs`), replace that line with

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
```

`mymodule.o` will be built according to `mymodule-objs` and then turned into `mymodule.ko` using modpost.
And as said before, you're missing `modules` in your `$(MAKE)` line

Answer (score 0):

Try modelling your Makefile after this?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122095/understanding-a-make-file-for-making-ko-files

You might not need `mymodule-objs := a.c b.c`. And I think you're missing `modules` after the `$(MAKE)` line